# JQM Popup doesn't popup when url has GET details in it

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

I have a page which displays a calendar/diary and lets you navigate back and forth using a form so the URL often looks like:
calendar.php?&month=6&year=2014

The popup works fine initially before there is any string after the .php.  However, once the "&month=" etc is there the popup doesn't work.  I note as soon as the popup loads it shows up #&ui-state=dialog in the url.

Is there a simple solution for this? (Other than changing the form to method=post, which I haven't yet tried).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to add:

```
data-history="false"
```

to your popup `<div>`. That will avoid URL modification when the popup is open.

Comment: Thank you. This certainly stops an issue of when clicking submit in the pop up it used to require you clicking submit twice.  Unfortunately, it didn't help with the issue of having GET details in the url, but I've changed everything around to POST method instead and it's all working fine now. Thank you.